# How can I prevent a webpage from detecting I am running a script?

Tags: javascript, facebook, security, greasemonkey, userscripts

After experimenting with scripts on facebook.com, I noticed that for a couple of minutes it didn't allow me to connect to facebook.com. This happened more than one time so I suspect that Facebook doesn't like to mess with their code using userscripts.

The Stack Overflow question *[Can a website know if I am running a userscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548141/can-a-website-know-if-i-am-running-a-userscript)* answers the multiple ways a website can detect scripts.

Now I want to know how I can fool a website to not detect any scripts I may be running.
Is there a way to know what my userscript HTML changes trigger on the website?

Comment: You make sound it as if you're committing a kind of crime. IMO you're perfectly right to do in your browser what you want with the data that were sent to you.

Comment: Uh-huh. And site's author is perfectly fine to try to detect and prevent automation in things like online games or pretty much any other project that relies on user doing something manually.

Comment: I doubt that Facebook is checking for userscripts.  You probably triggered something else (login delays on bad passwords maybe) or it was just a coincidence that the webs were bogging down.  Also, when doing a lot of GM dev, Firefox often gets memory-bloated and slow.

Comment: From top of my head, if there's some well known "mass friending" or "mass voting" script, it well could be target of Facebook's detection system. Throttling could be in effect too if the script aggregates several different pages from FB.

Comment: @dystroy As i say below what the script does is that it encrypts and decrypts posts i make on the browser.So for facebook that means that if this script is used widely it can be a bad thing for profiling users for advertisement purposes.So YES this is a crime for facebook.

Comment: If you make requests, you're not just running a script locally. And it's very very easy to detect abnormal querying patterns... And normal for the site author to prevent it.

Comment: @BrockAdams It could be a coincidence.But if you are a profit spoiler for facebook than it would start checking for scripts.So the question remains.

Comment: @dystroy i am making requests.But not at facebook.com.The requests are done at another domain to call jsonp data for the decryption of the posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Firefox and Chrome there is no magic bullet to prevent detection, it is a process and an art...

The 3 *principle* ways that a site would detect a script are:

1. Out of sequence or too-frequent AJAX requests.
2. Changes to the page's code (HTML, global JS, or even CSS).
3. Unnatural mouse or keyboard action.

See ["Can a website know if I am running a userscript?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8548141/331508) for more information.

**Some countermeasures:**

1. For AJAX requests that your script makes:

   1. Use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), or similar, to analyze the traffic of normal AJAX calls.  Make sure that you send the same type of calls, in the same order.
   2. Make sure that your requests show the same headers and data as the page's.
   3. Do not send AJAX requests faster than the page does normally or faster than a user could reasonably trigger.
   4. Consider adding random delays to your script's requests, so that they are not uniformly timed.
   5. Beware of constantly changing fields in the page's requests.  Be sure that you know how to generate the correct value; don't just cut and paste.
2. For changes that you make to the page's code:
   The page can handle these either entirely locally, with it's own javascript, or it can also send back status or code fragments to the server.

   1. Block and replace the page's javascript.  Tools like NoScript, RequestPolicy, firewalls and proxies can be used to block the JS.
      Then use Greasemonkey to add your ***edited*** version of the page's JS.  Greasemonkey will run even if all of a page's JS is disabled.
   2. If the page phones status home, and that status changes in response to your script's changes, Intercept and replace those messages.  (This is not needed if you used the previous method.)  You will need a custom firewall, proxy, or router to do this.
3. For events that you trigger (mouse clicks, filling out fields, etc.):

   1. If the page checks for this, give it what it looks for.  For example, instead of a `click` event, you may need a `mouseover`, `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `mouseout` sequence.
   2. If that is not enough, then the countermeasures are the same as for changes made to the page's code (replace JS, intercept status messages).

**Important!**
In the rare event that you *are* battling a site that tries to thwart userscripts, it is like a war.  The webmaster can adapt to what you are doing, and the environment can constantly change.  So scripting for such a site is an ongoing process.

Comment: thank you very much.You are an expert at this.You answered both my questions.

Comment: You're welcome; glad to help and good luck.  Also, if you find *proof* that Facebook is checking for scripts, please let us know. (Code snippets and/or captured status messages would be good proof.)

Comment: I hate to necropost, but can a webmaster track the mouse position of your window? If you're running many scripted tabs in parallel I'd assume the mousepos would be 0,0 on all of them.

Comment: @Andrew, start with [a simple search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[javascript]%20title%3amouse%20title%3aposition). And, that's just the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Scripts are executed on user's side - your side. Therefore site's server code cannot know if you run anything or not.

There's two things to note however:

1. Site can deliver some script to be run on your computer that will inspect its environment and will report back if necessary. Those are most often targeted to detect **some specific** script that site owner don't want to have in its environment.
2. Site author can inspect your requests and analyze if they don't match patterns that would match regular communication from site supplied forms or AJAX. Missing keys or keys not matching hardcoded order in query, headers that identify automation clients or missing browser headers and things like that. Hitting throttling limits if you do requests automatically much faster than human user should fits this category too.

Otherwise if you generate exactly the same responses and don't leave traces in globally accessible environment, it is impossible for site to tell if you're using userscript with either server or client side checks.

Comment: i am creating a script to automatically find encrypted posts and decrypt them with the password i provide.So what the script does is that it alters the html code of the page.Is that in anyway the specific script that facebook would like to prevent?And still the question remains:Can i prevent somehow facebook to know i am running a script?

Comment: How do you "find" them? Do you query list of posts and then quickly fetch them? Then you're most likely hit throttling.

Comment: the encrypted posts have a specific keyword in front of them.Its like the post is "kkkkkjkhfkajhfiuhfuer",and the script searches for "kkkkk" and then takes the rest of the post and puts it in a link like myjsondomain.com/jkhfkajhfiuhfuer and this retrieves a json with the encrypted message.After that it uses the password you provide to decrypt the message.

Comment: This shouldn't be problem with userscript. Does your JSON providing server request FB in turn? Does it provide X-Forwarded-For or similar headers that indicate originator? This could be used for throttling too.