# Chrome Extension Context: Can websites detect the presence of a content script, and if so, what the content script is doing?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I understand that websites can detect the presence of a chrome extension by name, but I am not sure if they have any way of understand what the content script is doing, or if it is there at all. Assuming all this content script does is read the DOM and send it to the background page, will the existence of this content script be detectable to the website?

Comment: Sometimes, but it can be hard as long as you don't do abusive things to/with the website and you don't inject `<script>` nodes. .. Related: [Can a website know if I am running a userscript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548141/can-a-website-know-if-i-am-running-a-userscript)

Comment: No, websites cannot detect the presence of a Chrome extension. The exception is if the extension has something in web_accessible_resources.